# Color difference between 2 objects in Object Mode/Solid View

Tags: materials

Blender 2.79
Two objects with identical material settings and no texture.
Viewed in Object Mode/Solid View the one on the left has a dark, bluish tint. The two look identical in other views and render with identical colors. But why the different colors in Solid View?  A minor but nagging and annoying nuisance. Much thanks from a newbie.[image: BLENDER COLOR PUZZLE]

Comment: The normals on the left object are flipped (facing the inside of the mesh). Select your left object, go to edit mode, hit 'A' to select everything, then hit 'Ctrl+N' to make the normals consistent or go to Menu - Mesh - Recalculate Normals/Flip Normals'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left object doesn´t have average normals. I can see it because on the bottom there's a black face and there's a different color on the object.
Enter edit mode. Select all faces, press CTRL+N to average normals. Your object is now of the same color than the right one.